# How does OpenGL know which image unit to attach to a uniform?

Tags: c++, image, opengl, graphics, textures

When loading textures to texture units I usually have to find the location of a texture unit and load the unit to teh unform, in which looks somehow like this:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + texture_unit);
glBindTexture(target, textureID);
//Get the uniform location in the program and attach the texture unit
GLuint location = program->get_uniform_location(uniform);
glUniform1i(location,texture_unit);
```

However I have a program that is using image3D and the only line that I call to bind the texture to the image is:

```
glBindImageTexture(image_unit, textureID, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA8);
```

And then in the shader I sample it as:

```
uniform layout(rgba8) image3D image;

vec3 c = vec3(imageLoad(image, ivec3(v_uv,0)));
```

This outputs the expected values, regardless of what changes I make, so it seems to work just fine. This leads me to my question, how is OpenGL able to determine that the uniform `uniform layout(rgba8) image3D image;` is to be attached to the image unit through the use of:

```
glBindImageTexture(image_unit, textureID, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_RGBA8);
```

What would happen if I had multiple images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image unit assigned to `image` in your shader is 0, since this is the default for *any* uniform whose value you do not provide. And you didn't. In your case, 0 is probably the value of your `image_unit` variable. So it all works out.

It's best to do this correctly, by [assigning a binding to the image variable](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Images_in_the_context). If you're using modern OpenGL, you can [put this in the shader with the `binding` layout qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Binding). Otherwise, you have to do exactly what you did for textures (which, BTW, you could *also* assign in shaders with the `binding` qualifier): change the value of the uniform with `glUniform1i`.

Comment: Is there any preference of one vs the other? Is one method faster for example?

Comment: @Makogan: Faster? Setting the value is something you do *once*; performance is irrelevant.

Comment: Not if you want to recycle a shader for multiple purposes.

Example, using the same shader for different geometries that can't be rendered using instances and have different textures. In this case you would change which texture is attached to the shader

Comment: @Makogan: You don't attach textures or images to the shader. You bind them to units in the context, and provide those units to the shader. So... why would you ever *change* what unit a shader uses? Just bind the texture to the place the shader expects it to be.

Comment: I c, but wouldn't you still need to change them if you have more textures than texture units? I mean, you have say 120 different objects each with a different texture, so you cannot just bind all of them at once, you'll need to change at least one texture unit binding, won;t you?

Comment: @Makogan: You don't keep all your textures bound all the time. You bind the textures you need for a particular rendering command, and that's *it*. And you bind them to the binding points that the shader(s) you're using expect. That way, you can use different shaders without changing all of your texture bindings (your shadow map can always be in unit 12, for example).

Comment: And to do that I need to bind the texture again, through one of the two methods you described, right? And if that si the case, then which would be "better"?

Comment: @Makogan: "*one of the two methods you described*" I didn't describe *any* method of binding textures. I described methods for telling the shader which image unit it should look for to find a bound image. This is a ***separate process*** from binding the texture. If you're doing both at the same time, it's because you choose to do so, not because they're multiple steps in the same process.